# Changing shapes used for scale_shape() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following

```
y <- rnorm(10)
b <- as.factor(sample(1:4,10,replace=T))
qplot(1:10, y, shape=b)
```

How do I change the shapes that are used using `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The ggplot way to do it would be to use `scale_shape_manual` and provide the desired shapes in the `values` argument:

```
qplot(1:10, y, shape=b) + scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 5, 6, 15))
```

[image: result of above]

The shapes are the same as the usual 0-25 indexes: http://yusung.blogspot.com/2008/11/plot-symbols-in-r.html

Comment: This is a much better way of doing it, as it retains the legend and works with ggplot, not base graphics. I learn more about ggplot here everyday, thanks!

Comment: Hi, how can I change the size of symbols when you are using scale_shape_manual()? I tried using geom_point(size=4), but the output was double symbols (two sizes). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using qplot, the `size=4` needs to go inside the `qplot` call, not separately. If you add an extra `geom_point`, you're effectively creating a second layer. (This, incidentally, is why you shouldn't use `qplot` -- it's confusing.)

Comment: Don't forget that if you want color inside some of the shapes (values 19 - 25 or so, I think), you'll need to set the fill aesthetic, as the color aesthetic only corresponds to the border color in these cases. You can always set both, e.g. `ggplot(mydata, aes(color = MyVar1, fill = MyVar1)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 24):

To complement Harlan's answer, here is a references for the available shapes - start from 0 at bottom left and read right then up (10y + x):

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(0:129))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x%%10, y=floor(x/10), shape=factor(x), colour=x, size=10)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=df$x) + theme(legend.position='none') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:10) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:12) +
  scale_colour_hue() + scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(3))
```

[image: Shapes available in ggplot2]

Answer (score 6):

```
> y <- rnorm(10)
> b <- as.factor(sample(1:4,10,replace=T))
> qplot(1:10, y, shape=b)
> qplot(1:10, y, pch=letters[1:10], cex=6)
```

Is this what you mean? I imagine you can use any of R's plotting characters...

This may not be a very 'ggplot' way of doing this though, but the man page does read "You can use it like you'd use the 'plot' function.". :-)

[image]

Comment: `Error: scale_shape_discrete can deal with a maximum of 6 discrete values, but you have 10.  See ?scale_manual for a possible alternative`