# Creating new shape palettes in ggplot2 and other R graphics

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'd like to specify my own shape palettes for `ggplot2` at least as a vector for input into `scale_shape_manual`. I really like the paired shapes palette from JMP, but noticed R doesn't have some of these shapes. In particular, sideways triangles (e.g. `|>` or `<|`) or a filled upside down triangle (e.g. `\/`) are missing. Are these available anywhere? If not, how can I specify these extra shapes and is there a way to get `ggplot2` to use them in plots?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create your own shape palette by specifying the Unicode values for the characters you want. You can find Unicode values for various geometric shapes [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/25A0-25FF). For example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$carb %in% 1:4,], 
       aes(wt, mpg, shape=factor(carb), colour=factor(carb))) +
  geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("\u25BA","\u25C4","\u25BC","\u25B2"))
```

[image]

You can, of course, use Unicode characters in base graphics as well:

```
with(mtcars, plot(wt, mpg, pch="\u25BC"))
```

Not every Unicode character renders correctly. I'm not sure why, but it may have to do with which fonts you have installed.

Comment: Relatedly, I have found two packages to help with special symbols, fonts and emojis: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html (author Y.X. Qiu) and https://github.com/dill/emoGG/issues (author D.L.Miller)

Comment: I just noticed that, on my system, the red and green symbols don't appear in the ``R`` console (and don't get printed in the PDF), while they do appear in the ``RStudio`` console, but none of the 4 symbols get printed, even with ``cairo_pdf`` or ``cairo_ps`` devices... only option so far is to print as PNG.

Comment: @PatrickT I've noticed this also. In some cases, you can get the symbols to appear by specifying a different font face. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34083063/496488) where I did that. The [`extrafont` package](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/) is useful for adding new fonts.

Comment: Thanks eipi10, very useful!