# Make multiple lines in a black and white plot easier to distinguish

Tags: r, plot, graph, ggplot2, visualization

Say I want to plot the relationship between x and y for four different variables. The lines are all pretty close together, and the plot has to be black and white. Below I give an example in ggplot where I use the `linetype` aesthetic for the different variables. However, it is hard to tell them apart in the plot, since all the different kinds of dashed lines look similar. What other options do I have to make them easily distinguishable without using color?

```
library(ggplot2)
v <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each = 25)
x <- rep(1:25, 4)

set.seed(123)
y1 <- cumsum(rnorm(25))
y2 <- cumsum(rnorm(25))
y3 <- cumsum(rnorm(25))
y4 <- cumsum(rnorm(25))
y <- c(y1, y2, y3, y4)

ggplot(data.frame(x, y, v), aes(x= x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = v))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use levels of gray (to a point), or line widths. Or just split into panels with `facet_wrap`.

Comment: The grays / line width idea is great. However, the reader should be able to compare the lines directly within the same plot, so `facet_wrap` is less suited.

Comment: Or maybe you can just use a white background, and increase the size of the lines slightly with `geom_line(aes(linetype = v), size = 0.75) + theme_bw()`

Comment: Just to add another option to the arsenal, you can also create linetypes that are easier to distinguish. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34713257/496488) has examples.

Comment: Since you're using the default `theme_grey`, you could even plot a white line. A thicker line width helps make it more visible; you can also turn off the grid, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks guys! Lots of helpful tips here.