# Specifying a line type for grid.circle

Tags: r, graphics, r-grid

I am trying to draw circles using `grid::grid.circle` with dotted or dashed borders. The documentation references `grid::gpar` but the `lty` argument does not seem to do it.

```
grid::grid.circle(0.5, 0.5, 0.33, gp = grid::gpar(lty = 2))
```

gives

[image: grid-circle]

It does seem to process the argument, given that it can be used to turn borders off, like so:

```
grid::grid.circle(0.5, 0.5, 0.33, gp = grid::gpar(lty = 0, fill = "light blue"))
```

[image: grid-blue-circle]

However, that seems to be the only choice. Is there any other way to get different line types for the borders of the circle using grid graphics?

Edit: I am using R on windows and if I use the pdf device I get the correct results. However, specifying `lty` to `grid.rect` works just as expected so I can't quite figure out what's going on.

Comment: I get a dashed circle with `library(grid); grid.circle(0.5, 0.5, 0.33, gp = gpar(lty = 2))`. Maybe you need to call `grid.newpage()` between each `grid.circle` call, so that the previous plot is cleared from the device. For a greater variety of linetypes, see, for example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34713257/496488).

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks, but that did not do it. However, I now discovered that it seems to be device dependent, since if I call `pdf()` first it works just fine. I'm on windows, so maybe it's some bug with x11?

Comment: Maybe so. I'm on a mac.

Comment: I can reproduce this on windows, using command line, rgui, and rstudio (works as expected on ubuntu): grid doesnt always play nice with windows