# How to decrease padding between lines and points in R "both" type plots

Tags: r, plot

I have tried to plot a series of points in R, and I use `type="b"` as a plot option.  However, there is a lot of padding (white space) between the points and the lines between them, so much that the line disappears entirely between some points.  Her is a picture of how it looks:

[image: example of disappearing lines]

I have tried to make the points smaller with the `cex` plot option, but this does not help, as it only changes the size of the points and not where the lines between the points between these starts and ends.  I do not know if this makes a difference, but the symbols I am using are `pch=1`.

I am interested in knowing if it is possible to reduce this padding, and how you do so.  I am not interested in using `type=o` as a plot option instead.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why aren't you interested in `type="o"`. It seems like the most straightforward way, in base graphics, to get what you're looking for.

Comment: @eipi10:  I did not know about the `bg` option, and without this it did not look anything near what I wanted.  I find `?par` a bit difficult to find help in as there is an infinite number of parameters, and very little space to describe them.  I would not be surprised if one of them just said *Mostly harmless*.

Comment: Well, at least it's countably infinite. For the point markers, you can do `?pch` and scroll down to see what's available (you can also use [Unicode symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30743128/496488) to get a much larger palette of marker options). I agree about the help files. When I first started using R, I found the help files somewhat mystifying. They slowly became more useful as I developed intuition about how R works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a dataframe named `dfs` this seems to deliver a mechanism for adjusting the surrounding "white halo" to whatever size of point an halo you want by adjusting the 'cex' values of the white and black points :

```
plot(y~x,data=dfs, type="l")
  with(dfs, points(x,y, pch=16,col="white",cex=1.4))
  with(dfs, points(x,y,cex=1) )
```

Answer (score 5):

Any particular reason why you don't want to use `type="o"`? It seems like the easiest way to get the effect you want:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(10)
dfs = data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))

plot(y~x,data=dfs, type="o", pch=21, bg='white')
```

`pch=21` is a circle marker like `pch=1`, but with both border and fill. We set the fill to white with `bg="white"` to "cover up" the lines that go through the point markers.

[image]

You can also use `cex` to change the marker size to avoid overlap and make the lines between nearby points visible:

```
set.seed(10)
dfs = data.frame(x=1:100, y=cumsum(rnorm(100)))

plot(y~x,data=dfs, type="o", pch=21, bg="white", cex=0.6)
```

[image]