# single legend based on color and shape

Tags: r, plotly

I have a data frame with 12 students and their scores, and there are no plotly color pallets that would work with this many groups.  I am trying to make the legend off of color and shape instead, is there any way to do this?

```
data <- data.frame(name = c("Sara", "Matt", "Mike", "Alyssa", "Ryan", "Parker", "Sam", "Bo", "Tyler", "Jess", "Maya", "Sara", "Matt", "Mike", "Alyssa", "Ryan", "Parker", "Sam", "Bo", "Tyler", "Jess", "Maya"),  
                   grade = runif(24, 50, 100),  
                   age = runif(24, 15,20))
```

Comment: The "paired" and "Set3" palettes in `RColorBrewer` both have 12 colors.

Comment: I would like to use a combination of colors and shapes instead if possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than six shapes in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223857/more-than-six-shapes-in-ggplot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than six shapes in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26223857/more-than-six-shapes-in-ggplot)

Comment: similar, but i would like distinct colors and shapes. For example: green, purple, orange... triangles, squares, circles, diamonds. so each color is used 4 times, one by each shape